# How to find out the number of network interfaces available in a linux system?

Tags: linux, interface

I need to loop over the network interfaces available in Linux. I'm interested in all kinds of interfaces (loopback, ethernet, vlan, bridge) - whatever shows up in `ifconfig -a`.

Is there a way to enumerate the interfaces in Linux? By any command or by reading a file?

Comment: Well this works... `ifconfig -a | grep 'flags' | wc -l`

Comment: @orion, I would recommend using `ip` instead as it is a successor of `ifconfig` - `ip -o link show | wc -l`. See [this](http://serverfault.com/q/458628/145512) question

Comment: You might look at [`netdevice(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/netdevice)).

Comment: @Nikolay of course, that's what I would use, and others already posted that answer (and removed it). I just wanted to point out that from what OP did to the answer to his question isn't very far.

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone, adding the option "1" to the ls command will list output one item per line, e.g: `ls -A1 /sys/class/net
eth0
lo
usb0
wlan0` In fact, I was surprised to find the count using "wc -l" still works on the single line version of the command (ls -A). But there are likely other situations where the item-per-line output from ls will be preferable, or necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get a list of these interfaces on most systems from the following:

```
ls -A /sys/class/net
```

But [beware of parsing the output from `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) in your script.

#### Edit

To get a total number of network interfaces pipe the output of this command into `wc` as recommended in Nikolay's comment as in:

```
ls -A /sys/class/net | wc -l
```

Comment: Linux doesn't allow creating network interfaces with newline in their name, but it allows network interfaces whose name starts with `.`, so you'd need `ls -A` here.

Comment: Noted sir , ty :)

Comment: This shows all the interfaces. But i am interested in the count.(total no of interfaces)

Comment: @user1762571, use this command `ls -A /sys/class/net | wc -l` or `ip -o link show | wc -l`